# sending mail works with mailtrap but not with an outlook server or other

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, django-forms, smtp

I made a contact form, I tested with the mailtrap service and it works I receive the messages well.

But when I put the smpt parameters for a real mail account I have this error message

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused at /contact/

{'info@mysite.net': (550, b'relay not permitted: you must be authenticated to send messages')}
```

the smtp server and the mail account is on the host alwasdata.net, but I tested with an outloock account it's the same thing always this same error. it seems to come from the line in the contact method:

```
message,
                'info@mysite.net',
                ['info@othersite.net'],
                fail_silently=False,
```

in settings.py i have this config

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "info@mysite.net"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-blablabla.net'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

in a views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Message d'un visiteur sur votre site"
            body = {
                'Nom': form.cleaned_data['first_name'],                    
                'Tel': form.cleaned_data['tel'], 
                'Email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                'Message':form.cleaned_data['message'], 
            }
            message = "\n".join(body.values())

            try:
                send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                'info@mysite.net',
                ['info@othersite.net'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('/')
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'pages/email_form.html',{'form':form})
```

the forms.py

```
from django import forms
    
    
    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    tel = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

Comment: Which email service you are using?

Comment: to test I used mailtrap.io, sending and receiving mail works but with the server at alwaysdata it gets stuck. I tried looking on outlook accounts, it doesn't work either.

Comment: See you have to use multithreading or need to wait after sending mail also close the connection cause sometimes connection remains alive.

Comment: Read carefully :- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/

Comment: I changed a few parameters, I put all the email addresses on the servers where my site is hosted, and in the host parameters I redirected to the final target email. And now it's work

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few parameters:

I put all the email addresses on the servers where my site is hosted,

```
try:
                send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                'info@mysite.net',
                ['info@mysite.net'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

and at my host I changed the parameters of the mail server so that it redirects to the email address that I was targeting. Now it's work